# Equation box in Quill is not completely visible

Tags: quill

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETLRt.png)

Trying to use Quill in my project. I'm using Bootstrap class 'row' with two columns. Right hand side column has Quill, everything works fine except this equation box (see in the image). Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using **bounds**. Here is the code snippet:

```
let quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
            modules: {
            formula: true,
            syntax: true,
            toolbar: '#toolbarOptions'
            },
            placeholder: 'Compose your question here...',
            theme: 'snow',
            bounds: '#editor-container'
        });
```